# how to open a dialog over topmost form window in C#

Tags: c#, forms, dialog, topmost

i have a C# program that i made that uses forms to display the control for the user.
the main form open other forms on top of it, each new form is set to `topmost`

in the program i call for [PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) in order to make a new PDF file, but i can't see the dialog becouse of the form that is set to "topmost"

is there a solution to this out the

Comment: Yes stop messing about with topmost, you get this sort of issue. User should be able to move forms about as they wish, and your UI shouldn't be dependant on the Z order, becasue it's not in your application's control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is.

Don't set the topmost flag on your forms.

There is no way to say "Stay on top of all forms, *except* ...".

Stay on top really means *stay on top*, if you don't want that, don't use it.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to use `.ShowDialog()` instead of `.Show()` without TopMost. This will basically mean that new Forms created by your app will have to be closed if you would like to get to the bottom form (I guess that's why you use TopMost - to prevent doing stuff on forms that were opened before?)